# How to add up the values of a single property in an object array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have this array:

```
var foo = [{name: "one", number: 1},{name: "two", number: 2},{name: "three", number: 3}]
```

Now I want to output the sum of all numbers into a div. I came up with this:

```js
var bar = 0
foo.map((n) => { bar = bar + n.number })
    
return(
    <div>{bar}</div>
)
```

Is it possible/recommended to add up all the numbers just using the space between the div tags? `<div>{here}</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `reduce` instead:

```
<div>{foo.reduce((a, { number }) => a + number, 0)}</div>
```

But while that's possible, I think that's a bit much to be putting into inline JSX. I'd slightly prefer to declare the total up above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.reduce`

```
<div>{foo.reduce((sum, i)=>sum+i.number, 0)}</div>
```